# angular.js:13424 TypeError: $scope.entry.update is not a function. Updating the correct way with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to make an update to an existing object but get the following error `$scope.entry.update is not a function`.

I created a service called 'budgetResource'

```
"use strict";
angular.module("common.services").factory("budgetResource", ["$resource", "appSettings", budgetResource])

function budgetResource($resource, appSettings) {

    return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "api/budget/:id", null, 
        {
            'update': { method: 'PUT', isArray: true },
            'delete': { method: 'DELETE', isArray: true },
            'save': { method: 'POST', isArray: true }
        });       

}
```

Herewith the function in my controller where budgetResource service is injected with the function $scope.updateBudgetAmount being called.

```
$scope.updateBudgetAmount = function (categoryId) {

        $scope.entry = new budgetResource();
        $scope.entry = {
            "budgetAmount": $scope.budgetAmount,
            "categoryId": categoryId
        }
        $scope.entry.update({ id: categoryId },
            function (data) {
                $scope.categories = data;
                $scope.category = "";
            },
        function (error) {
            $scope.message = error.statusText;
        });
    }
```

which in turn calls the webapi method

```
 public IHttpActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody]Category cat)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            BudgetRepository repo = new BudgetRepository();
            var categories = repo.SaveCategory(cat);
            return Ok(categories);
        }
```

How can modify this so that it is dine correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you do `$scope.entry = {...}`,`$scope.entry` becomes a plain javascript object, so `$scope.entry.update` is not exist.

Comment: Cool thanks, did this  $scope.entry.$update({ id: categoryId }, which did the trick